# Installing the fourier package to TeXLive 2012/Debian Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: packages, installing, texlive, ubuntu

I installed TeXLive from TUG 2 months ago and I just updated the packages. I'm trying to use the fourier package, but the terminal says it's missing. I was told that TeXLive should contain the fourier package by default. But after updating and rerunning pdflatex I got the same error which is fourier.sty could not be found. 
I tried to install it manually. But I can't add the package and extract it to the directory of TexLive.

Comment: Run `tlmgr install fourier` (with appropriate privileges, as when you do updates)

Comment: @egreg I also tried this, it's saying it's not valid and suggests commands like vlmgr and nlmgr.

Comment: Are you sure you installed the TUG TeX Live and not Ubuntu's?

Comment: As Ubuntu's outdated packages are not managed by tlmgr and TeXLive 2012 is frozen, and you cannot `tlmgr install nothing`, I think that is the best moment to install TeXLive 2013, in spite that is still a pretest.

Comment: @egreg what do you mean with Ubuntu's? I used the commands on the TUG page and while compiling through the terminal I read TeXLive 2012.

Answer (score 17):

You have to install `texlive-fontsextra`. That should work.

EDIT: texlive-fonts-extra
In Ubuntu, install it using

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
```

Comment: Now named `texlive-fonts-extra`

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver. Fourier package can be installed by the `texlive-science`. I fixed this problem by using the command below.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-science
```

**EXTRA:** Most of the font styling is done using this `Fourier` package, especially, antique styling.

Comment: This question is five years old.  Are you seriously still using Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 0):

For fedora, after executing:

```
dnf provides */fourier.sty*
```

It may be noticed that the package that provides the font is `texlive-fourier`, so after installing it, the issue was solved.

Comment: The question specified Debian. The equivalent on that distro would be `apt-file`.